# Java Code Analysis Rule for Commented Out Files

Tags: java, comments, sonarqube, code-analysis

I am using Sonar to run several static code anlysis tools (Checkstyle, PMD ...). I noticed that there is a *.java file that is completely commented out. Is there any static code analysis tool/rule to detect this?

Ideally I would like to have Sonar report this rule violation.

The Squid rule `CommentedOutCodeLine` does not catch this violation.

***Details:** Sonar 3.5.1*

Sample Code that is not caught:

```
//
//public class SandBox {
//    public Integer someMethod() {
//        return 0;
//    }
//
//    public static void main(String... args){
//        System.out.println("Hello from the SandBox!");
//    }
//}
```

Comment: This is the right rule to use and it works fine on my side. Could you please provide your commented out class?